# Access movie in external swf using xml data

Tags: java, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to access a movieclip inside an external swf (`.fla` file), using data from a vector?

The following code works correctly:

```
this._graphics.message2_mc.textLabel_txt.text = "Test";
```

Where as when I loop through a vector and try to replace "message2_mc" it cannot find the movie clip:

```
for(var i:uint = 1; i <= this._playlistState.subMovieVector.length - 1; i++) 
{
    var movieName:String = this._playlistState.subMovieVector[i].movieName;
    this._graphics.movieName.textLabel_txt.text = "Test";
}
```

Presumably this is because I am putting a string in the middle of the line of code accessing the movie clip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

var movieName:String = this._playlistState.subMovieVector[i].movieName; this.`_graphics[movieName]`.textLabel_txt.text = "Test";